# React Transition Group prevent transition on param change

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-transition-group

My application uses 'react-transition-group' to route between pages, but every time my portfolio id updates, it re-renders the entire component and runs the transition animation. How can I make it so that once you go to my portfolio page, it doesn't re-render the portfolio component when only the :id changes?

```
<Route render={({ location }) => (
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames='slide' timeout={800}>
            <Switch location={location}>

              <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
              <Route path='/portfolio/:id?' component={Portfolio}/>
              <Route path='/about' component={About}/>

            </Switch>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
      )}/>
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xccpfh here is a small reconstruction of the issue

Comment: this might be helpful, https://medium.com/onfido-tech/animations-with-react-router-8e97222e25e1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that is kind of hacky, but it works. I had to create a regular expressions that looks for anything after /portfolio and then use it to determine weather the key should be blank or not.

```
constructor() {
    this.omittedLocations = ['/portfolio', '/about'];
    this.omitLocations = this.omitLocations.bind( this );
}

...

omitLocations( location ) {

let key = 'randomtext';

this.omittedLocations.forEach( url => {

  let urlRegex = new RegExp( url + '(.*)' );

  if ( key != '' ) {

    let result = urlRegex.exec( location.pathname );

    if ( result ) {
      if ( result[0] ) {
        key = '';
      } else {
        key = location.key;
      }
    } else {
      key = location.key;
    }

  }

});

return key;

}

...

<Route render={({ location }) => (
    <TransitionGroup>
      <CSSTransition key={this.omitLocations(location)} classNames='slide' timeout={800}>
        <Switch location={location}>

          <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
          <Route path='/portfolio/:id?' component={Portfolio}/>
          <Route path='/about' component={About}/>

        </Switch>
      </CSSTransition>
    </TransitionGroup>
  )}/>
```